# pyramid beaker - session never expired

Tags: python, pyramid, beaker

I am currently developing application in pyramid framework. Following are my settings in development.ini

```
session.type = file
session.data_dir = data/sessions/data
session.lock_dir = data/sessions/lock
session.key = mykey
session.secret = mysecret
session.cookie_on_exception = true
session.cookie_expires = true
session.cookie_max_age = 120
session.timeout = 120
```

my problem is session never expired. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to setup pyramid_beaker properly during application startup as mentioned here

- https://pyramid_beaker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#setup

If you want more control, follow this way

- https://pyramid_beaker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#session-management

Remove the parameter below from your settings.
It is an option for `pyramid.session.UnencryptedCookieSessionFactoryConfig`. You switched to using pyramid_beaker.

```
session.cookie_max_age = 120
```